# How to add dynamically attribute in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dynamic, vue-component

I'm using vuejs and I wanna know how to have control on inputs (add disabled attribute when necessary). Is there any way to add dynamically attribute in vuejs ? Below my **Textfield component** :

```
    <template>
     <input type="text" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}" v-model="value">
    </template>
    <script>
    export default  {
      props: {
       disabled: {type: Boolean, default: false},
       placeholder: {type: String, default: ""},
       value: {twoWay: true, default: ""}
      }
     }
    </script>
```

**Usage** :

```
<textfield placeholder="Name" value.sync="el.name" :disabled="true"></textfield>
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can bind it to a variable using `v-bind:disabled="foo"` or `:disabled="foo"` for short:

```
<textfield label="Name" value.sync="el.name" :disabled="myVar">
```

Then in Vue you can just set `this.myVar = true` and it will disable the input.

Edit: add this to your template:

```
<template>
  <input type="text" :disabled="disabled" :placeholder="placeholder" v-model="value">
</template>
```

Comment: Note in the latest version of Vue that placeholder would also need to be `:placeholder="placeholder"`

Answer (score 25):

As pointed out, you don't need dynamic attributes in your case.

But well, you asked if it is possible, and the answer is yes. You can have dynamic attributes, as of 2.6.0.

Example:

```
<a v-bind:[attributeName]="whatever">
```

It is documented [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Dynamic-Arguments)

Comment: This's the answer I am looking for, thanks

Comment: `<a v-bind:[attributeName]="javascript code">` for example `<a v-bind:href="varRootPath + '/page.html'">`

Answer (score 5):

I am trying to figure out how to set the attribute of the html tags from the array value dynamically when using the Vue v-for loop.

What I am going to show:

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/black_horse/8u921rp3/1/)

1. There are 3 div elements with different background colors from array value(not static).
2. Each divs have a input tag and change the value when the user input value

   - The first div's input converts lowercase to uppercase.
   - second represents the mood, if enter 'happy', present 'good'. if enter 'sad', output 'bad'
   - The third div input doubles the input value.

   {{ box.outputData }}
         
         
         
           Rounded Box

   ```
   new Vue({
    el: "#app",
     data: {
       isRounded: false,
         boxes: [
           {
             inputData: "",
             outputData: "",
             color: "green",
             operation: "uppercase"
           },
           {
             inputData: "",
             outputData: "",
             color: "red",
             operation: "feeling"
           },
           {
             inputData: "",
             outputData: "",
             color: "blue",
             operation: "multiple"
           }
         ],
         feeling: {
           good: ["happy", "joyful", "calm"],
           bad: ["sad", "mad", "depressed"]
         }
     },
     methods: {
       toggle: function(todo){
           todo.done = !todo.done
       }
     },
     watch: {
       boxes: {
         deep: true,
         immediate: true,
         handler: function(val) {
           this.boxes.map(box => {
             if (box.operation === "uppercase")
               box.outputData = box.inputData.toUpperCase();
             else if (box.operation === "feeling") {
               box.outputData = this.feeling.good.includes(box.inputData)
                 ? "GOOD"
                 : this.feeling.bad.includes(box.inputData)
                 ? "BAD"
                 : "";
             } else if (box.operation === "multiple") {
               if (box.inputData == "") box.outputData = "";
               else box.outputData = parseInt(box.inputData) * 2;
             }
           });
         }
       }
     },
     mounted() {
       for (var i = 0; i < this.numBox; i++) {
         this.boxValue[i] = "";
         this.bxData[i] = "";
       }
     },
   })



   .clearfix{
    clear: both;
   }
   .full-width{
     width:100%;
   }
   input {
     background: transparent;
     text-decoration: underline;
     color: white;
     border: none;
     text-align: center;
     font-size:30px;
   }
   .box {
     float:left;
     color: white;
     width: 24%;
     margin-right: 1%;
     padding: 20px;
     background: blue;
     height: 100px;
   }
   .box-output {
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     font-size:30px;
   }
   .box-rounded {
     border-radius: 50px;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

base one condition we can define or change attributes in vue

Please refer official document for the same https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

Comment: please add an example, not a link

Comment: There's a really good example behind the link, thanks for pointing there. I somehow missed it

Comment: you can add an attribute like v-for="(item, index) in numbers" :mycustom="item" , if there's an array [1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 2):

ok, try this if you are passing i18 -

`:placeholder="$t('languagePlaceholder')"`

Answer (score 0):

I did that with checkboxes:

```
 <select id="newTwootType" v-model="state.selectedTwootType">
      <option 
      :value="option.value" 
      v-for="(option, index) in state.twootTypes" 
      :key="index">
        {{ option.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
```

my scripts

```
export default {
name: 'CreateNewTwootPanel',
setup(props, ctx) {
  const state = reactive({  
      selectedTwootType: 'instant',
      twootTypes: [
          { value: 'draft', name: 'Draft' },
          { value: 'instant', name: 'Instant Twoot' }
      ],
  })

  return {
    state,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, You didn't do that. Attributes of DOM elements are completely different thing than properties.

Comment: That worked fine for me a while ago

Comment: Ok, but title of this question is about attributes no properties. For example, on question: "What football player are the best in the wolrd?" You answered: "Justin Bieber.". Well he is not a football player.

Answer (score 0):

Vue3 Example with error:

**BaseInput.vue**

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <label>{{ label }}</label>
        <input v-bind="$attrs" :placeholder="label" :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
        <p v-if="error">{{ error }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps(['label', 'modelValue', 'error'])
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>
```

`v-bind="$attrs"` is necessary if you want to pass attributes to child tag or there are multiple tag in `<template>` you can specify with tag need to get attributes.

**Login.vue**

```js
<template>
    <form @focusout="validateForm" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <BaseTitle title="Log in" h="h1"/>
        <BaseInput type="email" v-model="email" label="Email" :error="emailError"/>
        <BaseInput type="password" v-model="password" label="Password" :error="passwordError"/>
        <BaseButton type="submit" label="LogIn" />
    </form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

const email = ref('')
const password = ref('')
const emailError = ref('')
const passwordError = ref('')

function validateForm() {
    emailError.value = "Error"
}

function onSubmit() {
    signIn({ email: email.value, password: password.value})
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set an attribute whose name is dynamic (e.g. a variable), one can pass a [dynamic argument](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#dynamic-arguments) to `v-bind` using square brackets.

```
<div :[attrName]="attrValue">Content...</div>
```

This is the shorthand for `v-bind:[attrName]="attrValue"`.

See [Vue SFC Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9kDFPwzAQhf+KdUuXqhm6hRQJUAcYCgI2zGClR3BxbMs+h0hV/jvnRAkMqJv93vfO73yGG+83XUIooYp10J5EREr+Wtra2UhCEYWDalHshIROmYQSrqStiolmji+ErTeKkG9CVNr6RKJ8m6PvOwmr6HgG51cSRMFcVSwhWANFfu1DN5tTdJa7nPMgCbVrvTYYHj1pbiOhFKOTPWWM+34YNQoJ17Nef2L99Y9+in3WJDwFjBg63mPxSIUGabL3Lwfs+byYrTsmw/QF8xmjMyl3nLDbZI9c+w83tr1vvQukbfMa9z2hjfNSuWgmh5Hnf054d2H137rbzXbMSTvA8AMHA5gG)