# Add condition in vue attribute instead using v-if condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm sorry for the vague title since I'm confused what should I write in the title regarding this problem,

So, I want to make a component layout using `vuetify` grid. I know exactly how to make it if I want to achieved it normally such as this:

```
<template>
 <v-flex v-if="totalMenuShowed=== 4" xs12 md6 xl6>
  <div>
   // some component
  </div>
 </v-flex>

 <v-flex v-else-if="totalMenuShowed=== 3" xs12 md6 xl4>
  <div>
   // some component
  </div>
 </v-flex>

 <v-flex v-else xs12 md12 xl12>
  <div>
   // some component
  </div>
 </v-flex>
</template>

<script>
  props: {
    totalMenuShowed: {
      type: Number,
      default: 4,
    },
  },
</script>
```

but what I want to know is

"**Can I give a condition based on value or props that I have without using `v-if` and directly modifying `xs12, md6, xl4` based on value that I got**"

for example such as below, since for the inside component `class` I can change it as I want using `@media screen` but I can't change the grid since I used it for another component below and I prefer not to change the grid value myself:

```
<template>
 <v-flex {totalMenuShowed === 4 ? xs12 md6 xl6 : totalMenuShowed=== 3 ? xs12 md6 xl4 : xs12 md12 xl12}>
  <div>
   // some component
  </div>
 </v-flex>
</template>
```

Can someone help me regarding this? I want to know if it is really possible to achieved this in vue?

Comment: You can make attributes dynamic with `:`. [How to add dynamically attribute in VueJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247411/how-to-add-dynamically-attribute-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make use of the `v-bind` and use a computed, like this:

```js
<template>
  <v-flex v-bind="vFlexProps">
    <div></div>
  </v-flex>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    totalMenuShowed: {
      type: Number,
      default: 4,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    vFlexProps() {
      return {
        xs12: true,
        md6: this.totalMenuShowed < 3 || this.totalMenuShowed > 4,
        ...
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, it really help me a lot since you give an example for this problem because I'm quite confused as how to search and apply the solution

Answer (score 4):

#### v-bind

You should be able to make the attributes dynamic. This is done with `v-bind:` or `:` for short.

- true-ish values will add the attribute
- false-ish values will remove the attribute
- string/number will show as their attribute value

```
<v-flex xs12 :md6="totalMenuShowed>=3 && totalMenuShowed<=4" :md12="totalMenuShowed<3 || totalMenuShowed>4"
  :xl6="totalMenuShowed===4" :xl4="totalMenuShowed===3" :xl12="totalMenuShowed<3 || totalMenuShowed>4">
  <div>
   // some component
  </div>
 </v-flex>
```

To make this more maintainable you can create `computed` values for these conditions if you like.

**v-bind** documentation: https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind

Comment: You're right, I can just use v-bind for this problem, thankyou for the explanation, it really help me, since I'm confused regarding what should I search for this problem