# How can I achieve custom rendering when overriding Vuetify v-data-table scoped item slots?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

```
<!-- DataTable.vue -->
<template>
  <v-card outlined>
    <v-data-table
      v-bind="$attrs"
      v-on="$listeners"
      dense
    >
      <template
        v-for="(_, name) in $scopedSlots"
        #[name]="slotData"
      >
        <slot
          :name="name"
          v-bind="slotData"
        ></slot>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Let's say every time I have a null value I want a specific render, how can I achieve this goal? I'll write some code to help you better understand my question.

```
  <!-- Relevant code snippet -->
  <slot
    :name="name"
    v-bind="slotData"
  >
    <template v-if="slotData.value">
      {{ slotData.value }}
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      -
    </template>
  </slot>
```

**Edit #1**

To achieve my goal I had to cycle through headers instead of scoped slots.

```
<!-- DataTable.vue -->
<template>
  <v-card outlined>
    <v-data-table
      v-bind="$attrs"
      v-on="$listeners"
      dense
    >
      <template
        v-for="{ value } in $attrs.headers"
        #[`item.${value}`]="slotData"
      >
        <slot
          :name="`item.${value}`"
          v-bind="slotData"
        >
          <!-- Here we can add any custom rendering logic we want -->
          <template v-if="slotData.value">
            {{ slotData.value }}
          </template>
          <template v-else>
            -
          </template>
        </slot>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

While this solution works, there are a couple of things to point out:

1. We are relying on slot names, which might be changed and break our logic.
2. We must reimplement some defaults. For example, arrays are now rendered like this

[image]

and no more like this.

[image]

To prevent this behaviour, we must update our code.

```
<!-- Relevant code snippet -->
<slot
  :name="`item.${value}`"
  v-bind="slotData"
>
  <template v-if="!slotData.value">
    -
  </template>
  <template v-else-if="Array.isArray(slotData.value)">
    {{ slotData.value.join(', ') }}
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    {{ slotData.value }}
  </template>
</slot>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to have some pre-configured props, instead of making a base data-table component. I would store my pre-config props as an object in a js file somewhere in my project, then I'd just import it and pass that object to the `v-data-table` with the `v-bind` property.

Kinda like what the correct answer did in this question:
[Add condition in vue attribute instead using v-if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72489278/add-condition-in-vue-attribute-instead-using-v-if-condition/)

Comment: Unluckly I really need a BaseDataTable component (I have shown a very basic example), so I need a more precise answer to my question.

Comment: If you are still interested, I edited my question.