# Why Vuetify v-data-table scoped item slots don't work as expected?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I've created a component based on `<v-data-table>`.

```
<!-- DataTable.vue -->
<template>
  <v-card outlined>
    <v-data-table
      v-bind="$attrs"
      v-on="$listeners"
      dense
    >
      <template
        v-for="(_, name) in $scopedSlots"
        #[name]="slotData"
      >
        <slot
          :name="name"
          v-bind="slotData"
        ></slot>
      </template>
    <v-data-table>
  <v-card>
</template>
```

I was wondering, why if I add this

```
<!-- Relevant code snippet -->
<slot
  :name="name"
  v-bind="slotData"
>
  DEFAULT RENDER
</slot>
```

and use my custom component

```
<!-- UsersDataTable.vue -->
<template>
  <DataTable
    :headers="headers"
    :items="users"
  ></DataTable>
</template>
```

result looks like this

[image]

and not like this?

[image]

**Edit #1**

Better discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72506915/how-can-i-achieve-custom-rendering-when-overriding-vuetify-v-data-table-scoped-i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default slot content is used only if parent component does not provide the content for that slot. But since your slot **is defined for each slot content provided by the parent** the content always exists and default is never used

**Edit (after question edit):** On the other side, if you do not pass any slot content into your `CustomDataTable` (last code example), `$scopedSlots` is empty, `v-for` is not executed, no slot content is passed into `v-data-table` and it uses default rendering...

Comment: I edited my question, maybe it wasn't clear. I still don't understand why it doesn't show 'DEFAULT RENDER' even though I'm NOT using any item slot inside child component.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove `slot` from this code. Becuase when you define the slot, you're ignoring The content inside it.

```
<template
  v-for="(_, name) in $scopedSlots"
  #[name]="slotData"
>
  <slot
    :name="name"
    v-bind="slotData"
  >
    DEFAULT RENDER
  </slot>
</template>
```

Also, there is another slot you have to define. Let me introduce the final code inside your `CDatatable` Component:

```
        <template
          v-for="slot in Object.keys($scopedSlots)"
          :slot="slot"
        >
          DEFAULT RENDER
        </template>

        <template v-for="(_, name) in $slots" #[name]>
          DEFAULT RENDER
        </template>
```